# testing equality with Dicriminated union in a list

Tags: f#, equality, discriminated-union

I have defined different types :

```
type TypeNull() = class end

type MyType1 = {
    a:int;
    b:int
}

type MyType2 = {
    a:string;
    b:int
}

type MyType3 = {
    a:string;
    b:DateTime
}
```

and different disciminated union that use them :

```
type myDU =
    | A of int
    | B of string
    | C of string

type myDU2 =
    | D of MyType1
    | E of MyType2
    | F of TypeNull
```

I have on function that map myDU to myDU2 :

```
let applyArray = function
    | A x -> [E({a="1"; b=2})]
    | B x -> [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});E({a="5"; b=24})]
    | C x -> [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});F(TypeNull())]
```

and then two tests to test equality :

```
let arrayValueEquals =
    let expected = [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});E({a="5"; b=24})]
    let actual = applyArray <| B("xxx")
    actual = expected

let arrayValueNullEquals =
    let expected = [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});F(TypeNull())]
    let actual = applyArray <| C("xxx")
    actual = expected
```

Which in fsi gives :

```
val applyArray : _arg1:myDU -> myDU2 list
val arrayValueEquals : bool = true
val arrayValueNullEquals : bool = false
```

My question is as follows, why does the first test succeeds and not the second one?

here is the complete gist :

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.net. See the 'F# Tutorial' project
// for more guidance on F# programming.

#load "Library1.fs"
open test2
open System

type TypeNull() = class end

type MyType1 = {
    a:int;
    b:int
}

type MyType2 = {
    a:string;
    b:int
}

type MyType3 = {
    a:string;
    b:DateTime
}

type myDU =
    | A of int
    | B of string
    | C of string

type myDU2 =
    | D of MyType1
    | E of MyType2
    | F of TypeNull

let applyArray = function
    | A x -> [E({a="1"; b=2})]
    | B x -> [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});E({a="5"; b=24})]
    | C x -> [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});F(TypeNull())]

let arrayValueEquals =
    let expected = [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});E({a="5"; b=24})]
    let actual = applyArray <| B("xxx")
    actual = expected

let arrayValueNullEquals =
    let expected = [D({a=1; b=2});E({a="1"; b=2});F(TypeNull())]
    let actual = applyArray <| C("xxx")
    actual = expected
```

Comment: Did you print out the value of `actual` to see what it was? I suspect that TypeNull() is not what you think it is. Or have you tried sending expected and actual to F# Interactive to review the types.

Comment: it does give me : 
> TypeNull();;
val it : TypeNull = FSI_0002+TypeNull

Comment: >     let actual = applyArray <| C("xxx");;

val actual : myDU2 list = [D {a = 1;
                              b = 2;}; E {a = "1";
                                          b = 2;}; F FSI_0002+TypeNull]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In F# there is something called [Structural Equality](https://www.google.ch/#q=f%23+structural+equality).

In short: lists, arrays and Discriminated Unions support equality if their elements do support equality. For lists it will be an element by element comparison.

Basic Discriminated Unions support Equality out-of-the-box but objects don't and that's why once you add `TypeNull` to the list the comparison fails.

Try simply this:

```
type TypeNull() = class end
TypeNull() = TypeNull() // false
```

then

```
let actual = TypeNull()
let expected = TypeNull()
actual = expected // false
```

so, unless you explicitly define equality for your object, the default behaviour is that it will yield true only if the two instances are the same:

```
type TypeNull() = class end
let a = TypeNull()
let actual = a
let expected = a
actual = expected // true
```

but with DUs it works automatically:

```
type TypeNull = TypeNull
TypeNull = TypeNull // true
```

then

```
let actual = TypeNull
let expected = TypeNull
actual = expected // True
```

Comment: I used type a() = class end to "emulate" type a = {}. So it is not the same ?

Comment: Yes, but in F# that's not a Discriminated Union. That's a simple object. Objects by default are equal if the instances are the same. This is the same in C#.

Comment: I will chew what you told me this evening... I have to think about it. There is something I do not get, but it is the end of the day here so..

Comment: OK, change `type TypeNull()` to `type TypeNull = TypeNull` then remove the `()`from the instances. It should work.

Comment: The way to emulate the "empty record" is a single-case discriminated union, like in Gustavo's example.

Comment: thx all for your comments and answer. Everything is much clearer now.